# Permalink from WP_Query posts not displaying posts content

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a custom WordPress Theme from scratch and I want to display some news from a certain category. I am doing it with the following code:

```
wp_reset_query(); $args = array(    
    'type' => 'post',   
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'category_name' => 'oportunidades' ); 
$opp = new WP_Query($args);

while($opp->have_posts()) : $opp -> the_post(); ?>  
<h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>     
<?php  endwhile; ?>
```

The list of news are being displayed correctly, but when I click the link to a certain post, it will change the URL of the page, but not display the contents of the post. If I echo the title, contents, and hyperlink of the post, it will echo the correct information.

How can I fix this, so when I click the post it shows the contents of the post?

*note: I have created a file named content.php, but it has no code inside. Can that be the problem?

Comment: Well, just write: `Hello World` in `content.php` and see if it shows up? If it does, then it's that file being served and you need to output what you want in it! (A suggestion for the future, writing something like "hey" in a file and test would have been so much quicker than writing this question).

Comment: I wrote 'hello world on' content.php and when I clicked on it, it didn't didn't show the 'hello world'.

What keeps happening is that if I copy and paste the link of the post itself (from the dashboard) to a new tab, it keeps displaying my index.php page.